# jquery - execute function call after block of code is completed (which contains animation)

Tags: jquery

Always had trouble with how this works and never really got familiar with the 'correct' way to do this.  This is a small section of larger code, but the same idea applies.  Everywhere `App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);` is called I need to make sure it waits till the lines above it have completed.  There is animation happening, both jquery and css, and  `App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);` should not execute before those animations complete.

The code as is works, but not as it should as `App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);` is executing before the animations happening before it have completed.

I do know how long each animation is and nothing is more than 200ms, but I know timeout is not the answer as you cannot be sure it finished.  Is there a way to do a .done() or .promise() type method in this case?

```
$('#rlogo').on('click', '.rsideleft-toggler', function(e) {
    
    //if large screen view
    if( $('#sidebar-check').is(':visible') ){
        //toggle minimized sidebar
        if( $('body').hasClass('minimized') ) {
            $('body').removeClass('minimized');
            //show open submenus
            App.sidebarHideSubs(false, 200, 0);
            App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar); //**** only when above it is finished
        } else {
            $('body').addClass('minimized');
            //show open submenus
            App.sidebarHideSubs(true, 200, 0);
            App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar); //**** only when above it is finished            
        }
    }
    //mobile view so the button needs to show sidebar and wait for click to go to page or close it
    else {
        //toggle mobileshow sidebar
        if( $('body').hasClass('mobileshow') ) {
            //close it
            $('body').removeClass('mobileshow');
            //close open submenus
            if( $('body').hasClass('minimized') ) {
                App.sidebarHideSubs(true, 0, 200);
            }
            App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar); //**** only when above it is finished
        } else {
            //show it
            $('body').addClass('mobileshow');
            //show open submenus
            App.sidebarHideSubs(false, 0, 0);
            App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar); //**** only when above it is finished
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if `css` animation is finished, `animationend` event can be used

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAnimatedElement");

// For Chrome, Safari and Opera
x.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", cssAnimationEnd);

// Standard syntax
x.addEventListener("animationend", cssAnimationEnd);

// In Jquery 
$("#myAnimatedElement").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd',cssAnimationEnd)
```

Jquery animations accept a callback function for the same purpose

```
$('#myAnimatedElement').animate(
     { opacity: .5,
       height: "50%"
     },
     400, function() {
       // Animation complete.
  });
```

You can use these techniques simultaneously to detect if both CSS and Jquery animations are finished.

```
 $("#myAnimatedElement").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd',cssAnimationEnd)
 $('#myAnimatedElement').animate(
       { opacity: .5,
         height: "50%"
       },
       400, jQueryAnimationEnd);

 let cssAnimationFinished = false, jQueryAnimationFinished = false;
 
 function cssAnimationEnd(){
    cssAnimationFinished = true;
    if( jQueryAnimationFinished  ){
       // Do work work here ( Call any callback function )
    }
 }
 function jQueryAnimationEnd(){
   jQueryAnimationFinished = true;
    if( cssAnimationFinished ){
       // Do work work here ( Call any callback function )
    }
 }
```

You can include the logic in `App.sidebarHideSubs` function, and pass `App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar)` as a callback

```
 App.sidebarHideSubs(true, 0, 200, App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar));
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will play around with this and see what I can come up with.  One thing that sticks out to me is there is not one single element which is is being animated, but rather multiple within one.  In your example, if I were to test animation on `$("#myAnimatedElement")` would that cover all that happen on the child elements in it or not?

Comment: The `animationend` event supports bubbling, so animations happening on the child element will bubble up to the parent, but the parent event handler will be triggered for each child element. You can either define a queue and wait for all the events to complete or attach the event listener on element with the longest animation duration. As for the jQuery animations, you can push all the promises that are returned natively by the `.animate` function in an array and use `$.when.apply($, promiseArray).then( function(){ //done });` to know when every promise is resolved.

Comment: I'm kind of straying off path from what you posted in my own solution, but it was what you posted that got me pointed in the right direction.  Thank you again for the assistance with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) to do a task after animation.